# Ford Audio renaming

Tags: bluetooth

My Lumia 640 is linked to two Ford cars. My partner's Fiesta and my Mondeo. They both appear as "Ford Audio" on my phone's Bluetooth app.
How can I rename at least one of them so that I can distinguish between them. It is especially frustrating when I want to pair my phone to my car because by the time I have established to which one I am connected, the connection is timed out.

Actually, is it the phone on which I have to rename, or the car?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot edit a device name that appears on Bluetooth settings through Windows phone. However the [Gadgets app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/gadgets/9wzdncrfj3df) by Microsoft can help you solve your problem.

Renaming your device:

1. Install(Mostly pre-installed) & open the [Gadgets app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/gadgets/9wzdncrfj3df).
   [image: Welcome screen of Gadgets app]
2. Open the device you want to rename. (I suggest you do it carefully by identifying a connected device).
3. Navigate to Customise tab.
   [image: Customize tab]
4. Change the accessory name.

The next time you want to connect to your device/car,

1. Open Gadgets app
2. Click on the device.(The customised name will be shown)
   [image: Device screen]
3. Click connect.

> Actually, is it the phone on which I have to rename, or the car?

Renaming via the Gadgets app is a easy method. If it is possible you can rename the bluetooth device in the car itself. Renaming the car will change the name of the car in bluetooth settings, Gadgets app(unless you set a custom name) as well as other phones you use.